# Git push error with remote on Overleaf ! [remote rejected] master -> master (invalid files)

Tags: git, git-push

I committed my latest changes and did a `git pull`, but after that, when I try to `git push`, I get an error

```
remote: error: invalid files
remote: 
remote: hint: You have 1 invalid files in your Overleaf project:
remote: hint: biblio.bib (error)
```

Any tips to debug or solve the error ?

I tried to overwrite remote with `git push -f`, to no avail.

Comment: Any string prefixed with `remote:` is coming from the *other* Git (the Git to which you are sending your commits). They should tell you *why* they don't like your commits, but if they don't tell you why, you'll just have to figure it out on your own. *We* can't tell you why they don't like your commits either. :-) Maybe the Overleaf community can, but we in [tag:git] and [tag:git-push] can't.

Comment: for others with the same error, another possibility is that the name of the file is too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
git pull --rebase
```

then fixing merge conflicts made it possible for me to `push` to remote.